# dealing with lists in pandas

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a dataframe df:

```
    mAID    MAID    mPIDs   MPIDs
0   A       D   [X, Y, Z]   [X, W, L]
1   B       E   [X, Y, Z]   [Y, Z, W]
2   A       E   [X, Y, Z]   [Y, Z, W]
3   A       F   [X, Y, Z]   NaN
```

I want to generate a new column that has mPIDs that are in mPIDs but not MPIDs. ie

```
mAID    MAID    mPIDs       MPIDs       resultPIDs
0   A       D   [X, Y, Z]   [X, W, L]   [Y,Z]
1   B       E   [X, Y, Z]   [Y, Z, W]   [X]
2   A       E   [X, Y, Z]   [Y, Z, W]   [X]
3   A       F   [X, Y, Z]   NaN         [X, Y, Z]
```

I am fine also with replacing `NaN` with `[]`. I just don't know how. `.fillna` didn't work.

Comment: are the list always `3` values or they can be arbitrary?

Comment: it's arbitrary. It can be any length, from empty till 1000's.

Comment: Do for loop and set subset ?

Comment: A loop isn't practical as its a huge dataset, 100's of millions of rows. I plan on running this on HPC. I wonder though if there is a way to do with with lambda or a pandas function?

Comment: FYI, `lamba` is basically a loop.

Comment: If you mentioned data frame is huge , I do recommend for loop rather than apply

Comment: ok... then maybe that is the solution. How could we do that?

Comment: Actually I recommend not using columns for lists.

Comment: @cs95 I actually start with two tables the have the following columns: mAID, MAID, mPIDs   and mAID, MAID, MPIDs.  Wasn't sure how to compare them in any other way... I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make those non-lists into lists

   ```
   df.MPIDs = df.MPIDs.map(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [])
   ```
2. Use sets and set subtraction

   ```
   df.assign(resultPIDS=df.mPIDs.map(set).sub(df.MPIDs.map(set)).map(list))

     mAID MAID      mPIDs      MPIDs resultPIDS
   0    A    D  [X, Y, Z]  [X, W, L]     [Y, Z]
   1    B    E  [X, Y, Z]  [Y, Z, W]        [X]
   2    A    E  [X, Y, Z]  [Y, Z, W]        [X]
   3    A    F  [X, Y, Z]         []  [X, Y, Z]
   ```

---

Alternate

```
from collections import Sequence

def f(x): return {*x} if isinstance(x, Sequence) else set()
df.assign(resultPIDs=df.filter(like='PIDs').applymap(f).diff(-1, axis=1).iloc[:, 0])

      mAID MAID      mPIDs      MPIDs resultPIDS
    0    A    D  [X, Y, Z]  [X, W, L]     [Y, Z]
    1    B    E  [X, Y, Z]  [Y, Z, W]        [X]
    2    A    E  [X, Y, Z]  [Y, Z, W]        [X]
    3    A    F  [X, Y, Z]        NaN  [X, Y, Z]
```